# Aptana like color theme for emacs

Tags: emacs, color-scheme

Does anyone know where I can find Aptana like dark color theme for emacs?

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ae5b9073760aa7378c2121ee551600d6.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Solarised theme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) by Ethan Schoonover, which is somewhat similar. The emacs version is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized).

Comment: I am familiar with this theme. I like it but it's still not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This Aptana theme seems similar to Zenburn. You can find the Emacs version [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs). Alternatively you can simply modify an existing theme - the creation of a color theme for Emacs is a trivial process (and I should know since I'm the author of zenburn-emacs ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

[Twilight](http://emacsthemes.caisah.info/twilight-theme/) for Emacs 24
A port of the Twilight color theme using the new deftheme format.